# Windows 8 Mobile App + HTML5 + Web view

Tags: c#, html, xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I am creating an Windows 8 App which has 2 screens - 
1. Login
2. Dasboard

We have created 2 Html files, 2 XAML files for above given screens -

XAML - 
1. Login.xaml
2. Dashboard.xaml

HTML - 
1. Login.html
2. Dashboard.html

Initially, in App.config of project (Windows 8 mobile App) we have Login.xaml file which internally calls Login.html and this renders the Login screen. When User enters credentials we do a web service call and thus we get a response from web service in HTML. Now, if a User is Authenticated from web service how can i navigate to Dashboard.xaml which loads Dashboard.html internally.

We are not able to navigate from Login.html to Dashboard.xaml (which loads dashboard.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add webview control in login.xaml and load login.html in that webview.

Add a eventhandler to the navigation completed event of the webview.

In the eventhandler monitor the cookies or the redirect url using the params of the event. 
If it matches, navigate to the dashboard.xaml page.